# Difference between SimpleLogistic and Logistic in Weka

Tags: weka, logistics

I am working on Weka, but i cannot understand the difference between SimpleLogistic and Logistic classifier. Does anybody know the difference?

Answer (score 7):

According to the documentation ([SimpleLogistic](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/weka/classifiers/functions/SimpleLogistic.html) and [Logistic](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/weka/classifiers/functions/Logistic.html)), SimpleLogistic uses LogitBoost whereas Logistic uses a ridge estimator. The papers that describe the algorithms are

Niels Landwehr, Mark Hall, Eibe Frank (2005). Logistic Model Trees. Machine Learning 95(1-2):161-205 for SimpleLogistic

le Cessie, S., van Houwelingen, J.C. (1992). Ridge Estimators in Logistic Regression. Applied Statistics. 41(1):191-201 for Logistic.